# Creating a rank score based on Max value of measure

Tags: max, calculated-field, scoring, amazon-quicksight

I'm looking to create a scoring metric by taking the max value from a measure and then dividing that value by the other values within my view.

Example - Number of bookings by channel A-C

Dimension  :   Value

A     :         32

B      :        28

C       :        8

In the above instance, I would want to divide dimension B by A (Max) which would give 0.875 and then divide C by A to get 0.25

I am trying to do this in amazon quicksight.

Can anyone show me how to do this, I tried to create a max value as a calculated field but I couldn't get this to work as I don't think I was grouping correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to find the max cell within many *rows* and divide each row's cell by that max. If that's not correct and you'd like to do this against columns, let me know and I'll update this answer.

One easy way to achieve this, given the above assumption and another assumption that you wouldn't mind having a row for the max as well (always containing the value `1`) is to use [Level-Aware Aggregations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/level-aware-aggregations.html).

You'll want to add a new calculated field, that uses `PRE_AGG` to get the maximum value before aggregation, here I'm assuming your value column is `Value`

```
{Value} / maxOver({Value},[],PRE_AGG)
```

Adding `Value` and this calculated to a table yields

[image]